# How to visualise a set of interconnected XML objects?

Tags: xml, graph, visualization

I have some XML documents which, grossly simplified, can be described as:

```
<someobject id="mykey">
  <relatedobject id="hiskey"/>
  <relatedobject id="herkey"/>
</someobject>
<someobject ...
```

What would be a simple way to produce a diagram of this, showing the objects placed nicely in 2D space, with lines between them?

I'm very comfortable with XSLT and Xpath, but would prefer a solution that doesn't require writing a program from scratch. Making a few command line calls to Saxon then a graph generating prog would be ok. Bonus points for anything that can be done totally using online hosted tools. Extra bonus points for a live (eg javascript), interactive diagram.

Comment: I think you've forgotten to include the description you promised... unless you'd like us to explain how to produce a diagram of white space?

Comment: You have to indent code 4 spaces (or use the 101010 button in the editor), especially XML.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: also, gutch, did we by any chance go to school together? you wrote a network chat program called "gutch chat". There's no PM system here, so I won't out you any further than saying you would have had a female programming teacher with initials LK.

Comment: If you don't provide desired output this is not an XSLT question but a online services questions. Also you need to clarify if this requires schema inference. Also for UML diagram you have http://yuml.me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick solution that can can be directly pasted to a shell, using GraphViz as [suggested by Philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394787/how-to-visualise-a-set-of-interconnected-xml-objects/4394944#4394944). This makes use of [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to avoid having to write an XSLT stylesheet from scratch.

```
( echo "graph G {" 
  xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//someobject/relatedobject" \
    -v "concat(../@id, ' -- ', @id, '&#xa;')" input.xml 
   echo "}" ) | dotty -
```

Sample output:

[image]

---

**Edited to add:** And for the extra bonus points, an interactive SVG diagram using only online tools [here](http://www.w3.org/2000/06/webdata/xslt?xslfile=http%3A%2F%2Fpastebin.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fi%3DVyWKTpZ2&xmlfile=http%3A%2F%2Fpastebin.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fi%3DPDubXWMJ&transform=Submit). This makes use of [Dracula Graph Library](http://www.graphdracula.net/) and the [W3C XSLT Service](http://www.w3.org/2001/05/xslt). This required creating an [XSLT stylesheet](http://pastebin.com/VyWKTpZ2) (directly adapted from the online examples for Dracula Graph Library). The input document used for the transformation can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/PDubXWMJ).

Comment: wow, very clever - wish I really could give you bonus points :)

I got pretty close to implementing that solution for my own problem. not sure why it doesn't work: it runs fine locally.

view-source:http://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt/xslt?xslfile=http://pastebin.com/download.php%3Fi%3DY0JYrmaT&xmlfile=http://pastebin.com/raw.php%3Fi%3DakxLeD4e&transform=Submit

Comment: @Steve, got your example working with the following changes: (1) using the "Download" link to pastebin rather than the "Raw" link, and (2) fixing the XHTML namespace URI. http://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt/xslt?xslfile=http://pastebin.com/download.php%3Fi%3DpC3Je8zh&xmlfile=http://pastebin.com/download.php%3Fi%3DakxLeD4e&content-type=&submit=transform

Comment: you totally win: completely online, live visualisation of datasets in the Research Data Australia (or subsets thereof):

http://bit.ly/hJd9Cm

Very cool. Data is retrieved from the registry, sent to the W3C XSLT service, and fed into that 3rd party javascript graphics library, and all coordinated by the browser through a URL.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/): You create a text file using XSLT which describes the graph you would like. See [this example](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/undirected/fdpclust.html) for a quick overview.

I'm not too familiar with it anymore, but I think

```
graph G { 
  mykey -- hiskey
  mykey -- herkey
}
```

should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I've got this to work, although so far the results are pretty awful - for some reason neato is compressing all the objects too close together, resulting in a massive unreadable blob of overlapping text and arrows.

Comment: try using dot instead of neato, for me its layout algorithm is generally more successful.  Don't be put off by the fact that its for directed graphs - you can tell it not to put arrows on the lines.  e.g. 

` digraph G {
     main -> init [arrowhead="none"];
  }`

Comment: dot is even worse, because it's making a hierarchy, and my data is not at all like that. fdp is doing the best so far, though it's still pretty hard to control.

Comment: @Steve - Try adding `overlap=false`, for `neato` this seems to default to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple problem. I wrote a program a long time ago to cluster XML documents, but the display is a grid instead of a graph. Still, you might be interested in the code if you're going to implement something. Additionally, you can attribute keywords to your documents, and the keywords will be used as well as the links to cluster the documents, and they will also be used to name the resulting clusters. The grid display is probably better than a graph when there are lots of documents.

http://media4.obspm.fr/outils/clustering/doc_en.html